# Making and aligning empty boxes

Tags: boxes

I want to create three empty boxes aligned like so using latex, so that my students can fill in proton and neutron numbers and the atomic symbol for a radioactive decay worksheet.

Any ideas how I can do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `tikz`, it is as easy as this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[thick] (0,0)rectangle(1,1) (0,1.2)rectangle(1,2.2) (1.2,0)rectangle(2.7,2.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

You can use this in a `newcommand` for your convenience to insert it at your document wherever you want. You can also change the option `scale=1` as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `picture` mode or some low level programming.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\particle}[1][1cm]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox to 2.2\dimexpr#1\relax{%
    \hbox{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#1}\rule{#1}{0pt}}}
    \vfill
    \hbox{\fbox{\rule{0pt}{#1}\rule{#1}{0pt}}}
  }%
  \kern3pt
  \fbox{\rule{0pt}{2.2\dimexpr#1\relax}\rule{1.5\dimexpr#1\relax}{0pt}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

X \particle\qquad\particle[.5cm] Y

\end{document}
```

Adjust the default dimension (1cm) to your liking.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple code with `hhline` and a tabular environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{array, multirow, hhline}

\newcommand{\answerboxes}{%
\begingroup\setlength\doublerulesep{8pt}\setlength\arrayrulewidth{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|| p{4cm}|}
\hhline{|-||-|}
\rule{0pt}{2cm} & \multirow{2}{=}{}\\
\hhline{:=:|~|}
\rule{0pt}{2cm} &\\
\hhline{|-||-|}
\end{tabular}\endgroup}%

\begin{document}

\centering\answerboxes

\end{document}
```

[image]